# How to read out previously committed files without destroying later snapshots

Tags: git

Say, I have committed four times,

```
git commit -m "commit_4"
git commit -m "commit_3"
git commit -m "commit_2"
git commit -m "commit_1"
```

Now I wanna read out files preserved during `commit_2` to the working directory, if I use `git reset`, no matter `--soft` or `--hard`, `commit_3` and `commit_4` will be erased. Is there any way to read out files from the repository while keeping later snapshots?

Comment: What is the purpose of "reading out" the older files? Do you want to make a new commit with the old state, or do you only want to explore the old state temporarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout individual files at specific commits using the following:

```
git checkout <SHA-1 commit_2> path/to/your/file.ext
```

where `<SHA-1 commit_2>` is the hash of `commit_2`, and the path for `file.ext` is also given.